# Record Voice from microphone and monitor with delay

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

What I need to do is Record my voice using the microphone and simultaneously listen to what I am saying with latency.

I have tried using AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer (firing the AVAudioPlayer let's say 1 second later to play the file from the same nsurl as I am recording to) but that does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer both deal with discrete audio files.

You are going to need to deal with streaming audio. You probably want to AVFoundation and create both an `AVAssetReader` and an `AVAssetWriter`, connect the reader to the microphone, and connect the writer to an output stream.

AVFoundation is tricky to figure out. I haven't worked with it in quite a while, and I'm no expert. I suggest you do some digging using those specific search terms.